# how to avoid Out of Mem error in Remix IDE, running a solidity smart contract?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I am a complete newbie to solidity, and I am trying out some projects for my learning, I have been primarily relying on the Remix browser IDE for my development and testing till now, but due to recent addition of some date and string utility methods(for string to time conversion and string splitting)  , whenever I call the particular method that uses these utils, the IDE crashes and show out of mem exception.

I understand I may be doing too many operations, causing the mem to run out, I have tried optimizing the code a bit, tried disabling auto-compile, and enabled optimization, but no help so far.
The utility methods I have added so far are for converting date in string format to epoch timestamp, since I couldn’t find any solidity lib compatible with my version of the compiler, I had to resort to writing the lib methods myself, which I suspect are not every gas efficient
but gas is not an issue at this point, since this contract is not meant to go live, and is for my own learning, so any insight into how to avoid out of mem or the dateTime and String utils libs would be really helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: IDE running out of memory on a simple smart contract sounds like a bug. Have you tried reporting it in https://github.com/ethereum/remix-project/issues?

Comment: @cameel no, I haven't reported this as a bug, I am suspecting that the number of operations I am doing for converting the string data to epoch time is just not efficient at all ,for instance i am splitting the string into hours,  minutes seconds, days months years and so on, and then converting each of these strings to bytes and then to uint(as I couldn't find a direct way of converting string to uint) and then further processing to get the epoch . All this is just one part of a single and much larger function call.

Comment: Splitting it into `bytes`/`string` indeed does not sound very efficient because they allocate memory (in the EVM) and in Solidity memory is never freed. String date representation should easily fit into `bytes32` so you could avoid dynamic in-memory arrays and work with that value type instead. This should help if your contract is allocating so much EVM memory that it does not fit in your RAM during contract execution.

Comment: You could also try a framework like Truffle, Hardhat or Brownie. This would let you execute your code on ganache. But this will only help if it's either Remix itself (rather than EVM) running out of RAM or the amount of RAM your browser can use is artificially limited. Otherwise you'll likely see the same effect as in Remix.

Comment: @cameel I have all date time operations using epoch timestamp in uint256 format, only when I make a call to the oracle chainlink i get the date in the aforementioned string format, hence the need for parsing and conversion to epoch timestamp. You made a good point about checking if the EVM is running out of mem or if its the browser based remix IDE - is there any way to check this? With regards to the frameworks - yes, I am planning to learn about truffle and ganache next.

Comment: You might try to check in a debugger like the one built into Remix or [Tenderly](https://dashboard.tenderly.co/explorer). But first I'd try to just roughly estimate how much it might be using based on your code.

Comment: But really, something does not add up here. A contract using so much memory that it crashes Remix will just immediately run out of gas when you deploy it to the mainnet so from your comment I assumed you want to run it off-chain or maybe as a staticcall that can be executed locally by the node. But you say you are new to this and not even familiar with frameworks so I somehow doubt you're doing things like this. You should add more detail to your question. In particular, what is the code you're trying to run and how exactly you're trying to run it. Otherwise it's all just guesswork.